# Replace superclass with customized class

Tags: java, inheritance

The situation is like:

```
class1
class2 extends class1
class3 extends class1
class4 extends class1
...
```

I want to replace class1 with a customized one and all class that inherit from class1 automatically inherit from the new class without "re-declare" the class

```
class1
class1a extends class1

class2 extends class1 -> automatically extends class1a
class3 extends class1 -> automatically extends class1a
class4 extends class1 -> automatically extends class1a
...
```

It's just like GWT's replace-with tag. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: If ALL your subclass that class1 want to change to class1a, I don't understand why keep class1. If not, there's must be some classes which extend class1.

Comment: because class1 and all of its subclass is part of some library/framework. I just want to add some little functionality to the super class, so every subclass automatically have the functionality, and offcourse, without editing whole library searching for the subclass

Comment: You don’t need to edit the whole library. You only need to edit `class1` to add the functionality.

Comment: @WilliamAnthony  - what kind of little functionalities do you want to add, and how do you want to use them (inside class2, class3, ?). Is it only new functions, used by objects you create ? , or do you want to change existing methods already in libraries ?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina sorry for late comment. I added several fields and some new methods, there is also a method I overide from the parent class. I use them as usual: instanceofclass2.newmethod(...)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do it?

Not without modifying the source code, or using some kind of source code preprocessing or bytecode engineering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it at a source code level, you can do it as follows.

Firstly, by using a refactoring capability of your IDE, rename `class1` to the desired class `class1a`, which is how all your classes will automatically changed to extend `class1a`.

Secondly, create class `class1` (with a content of class1a) which you renamed in previous step, and swap the content (manually, by using copy-paste) of classes `class1` and `class1a`.

Comment: class1 and all of its subclass is part of some library/framework. So it's inconvenient to alter them from source level.